# maven already installed, it's just not linked

Tags: macos, maven

I installed Maven on my Mac with version 3.0, when I type `mvn -v`, it shows:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 21:51:28+0800)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven30/3.0.5/libexec
```

Then I installed maven latest version which is 3.2, I was trying to point mvn to this newer version. I followed a method as

```
brew update
brew unlink maven
brew install maven
```

after unlink from maven, I tried to install maven again. But it shows `maven-3.2.5 already installed, it's just not linked` and `mvn -v` still shows version 3.0.5

My question is how can I point to the newer version of maven on Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are maven folders inside `/usr/local/Cellar/`

Delete all maven folders and re-run `brew install maven`

`mvn -v` shows it is the latest version